# Autofilter using array as criteria max size

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, limit, autofilter

So this is kinda a weird one but:

I have an excel sheet with a few hundred thousand rows of customer data. I have a sheet with 70,000 names and addresses to remove from the bigger sheet.

What I've done before with VBA is combine the names and addresses into one column (on both sheets) and then I put all of the combination name+address cells into an array, then use the `autofilter` with the array of names + addresses. that shows me all of relevant names + addresses.

However I've never had 70,000 rows to get rid of, and I've discovered that the max number of values you can use in filtering with an array is 65536. I imagine this has to do with the fact that 65536 is the biggest int you can have, and the largest number represented by 16 bits, etc...

does anyone know how I can use the autofilter with an array of values that is bigger than 65536?

Comment: Arrays directly are connected to how much memory you can maintain. the Autofilter is based off of your version of Excel and what you are trying to filter. What version of excel are you running? Additionally, have you considered pivot tables? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx

Comment: I am running Excel 2010. I have considered a pivot table but don't really want to use one. I may just have to break up my data into 2 sheets.. any other way?

Comment: If you know VBA, you can load up a scripting dictionary with name+address as key, then loop through your data (maybe first read the name and address columns into an array) and use the dictionary to flag rows to be deleted.  Or use your concatenated columns and a MATCH() worksheet formula then sort your data on the Match column.

Comment: Thanks for the answers / comments everyone, but I think what I'll do is include something to stop when I've reached 60,000 rows. then I can filter for those 60K, delete, then continue.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution is to add a new column in your customer data sheet with a countif(), counting how many times the address of the customer data exists in the address sheet. Then filter on the ones with 0 and delete those rows. 
Sorry for not giving exactly the answer on your question, but this could be a way to go...

Comment: I guess I could adapt that to use a match function as well to find the specific row the address-to-remove appears on, and loop that until the match returns -1 (or whatever the result for no match being found is) or until the countifs for all the rows in the sheet with addresses to remove are 0.. but I think I'm just going to adapt my current solution a little bit. (see my last comment on my question)thanks for the suggestion though :)